# How to find my product key for windows XP?

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a product key finder for a PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/176306/is-there-a-product-key-finder-for-a-pc)

I have my WindowsXP laptop the product key sticker on it has fadded out..How do I find its product key? I have my laptop running on it!!

Comment: Use one of these tools: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/productkeysactivation/tp/topkeyfinder.htm

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of freeware tools available for this.  My personal favorite in the past has been Magical Jellybean Keyfinder:  http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/