# Retrieve Windows 7 Product Key from Linux

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, product-key

My Windows 7 is corrupted and no way I can get this repair tool working. The good thing is that I can format and make a fresh install, the bad thing is I lost the product key (I have the DVD). Right now I'm using an Ubuntu cd, and I think my registry is intact, so is there a way to get this product key using Ubuntu?

Comment: The product key should be written on your PC's case, if you bought it with an OS...

Comment: no, the Vista installation is written in my notebook, but I won an upgrade DVD for 7 because I bought it near the launch of windows 7, and that product key is in a DVD envelope that I lost.

Comment: Check the recommendations in our community FAQ on [product key finders for Windows](http://superuser.com/questions/176306/is-there-a-product-key-finder-for-a-pc). I haven't used most of them myself, but some of them may support scanning the registry offline.

Comment: You will need an operational Windows PC....http://www.dagondesign.com/articles/windows-xp-product-key-recovery/comment-page-9/

Comment: After several hours I got Windows running with many errors, but was able to retrieve the product key using Magical Jelly Bean Keyfinder. Problem solved, but I think nhinkle and Moab tips were the right answer to my problem.