# reinstall XP OS but retain Office installation key?

Tags: microsoft-office

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a product key finder for a PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/176306/is-there-a-product-key-finder-for-a-pc)

Is there a way I can grab Office 2007 installation key from the already-installed and activated software? I no longer have the key, and I want to format the system, but I would like to reinstall the Office.

Also, as long as I activate it on only one computer, can/should I install it as many as times as I want? (I am thinking about Microsoft Virtual Machine that comes with 90-day expiry.)

Comment: also, covered on [su] blog: [Dude, Where Are My Keys?](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/03/dude-where-are-my-keys/)

Answer (score 6):

There are multiple programs out there on the net for retrieving installation keys.  [RockXP](http://majorgeeks.com/RockXP_d4138.html) for example.  Sure, it should trip your AV protection, as every other tool I know that will do the same thing, but it's a false positive.

**EDIT** and as far as reinstalling it more than once, you shouldn't have an issue.  Windows on the other hand... that's always touchy.

**EDIT-EDIT** and there's the [Magic Jellybean](http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/) and [Produkey](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html) just for a couple of others to work with.

Comment: I've had pretty good luck with magic jellybean, even if the current versions are nerfed compared to the old one. nirsoft's stuff is uniformly awesome ;p

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Produkey's got a nice minimalist feel to it, but believe it or not I kinda like RockXP's loud interface.  I mean, way more to it than it needs, and lots of fluff.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a tool to retrieve your product keys, I suggest **Microsoft Product Key Finder**: [softpedia.com/.../Microsoft-Product-Key-Finder.shtml](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Info/Microsoft-Product-Key-Finder.shtml)

Comment: This link doesn't work anymore.