# How do you print a list of currently installed programs and license keys in Microsoft Windows?

Tags: windows, software-rec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a product key finder for a PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/176306/is-there-a-product-key-finder-for-a-pc)

I'm preparing to do a fresh install of Windows 8 RTM and want to reinstall all my programs by hand.  Is there an easy way to list apps and licenses currently installed?

Comment: I wasn't just looking for keys; which would make this an exact duplicate.  I was looking for a list of *all* installed programs.  Belarc Advisor was the perfect answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had good experience with [Belarc Advisor](http://www.belarc.com).  It takes a while to run, but it's extremely thorough.

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  Creates an easily printable list. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

licensecrawler works great - http://www.klinzmann.name/licensecrawler.htm

If you just want your Microsoft key and office winguggle takes 2 seconds to find it.

http://unlockforus.blogspot.ca/2008/01/winguggle-get-your-windows-vista.html

Hope that helps