# How to get the product key of my windows 8 installation without an external program?

Tags: windows-8, product-key

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I find the product key that was used to activate Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/495794/how-can-i-find-the-product-key-that-was-used-to-activate-windows-8)

My question whether there is such a possibility and if yes how to get the key.

Comment: When you purchase Windows 8 you were sent the product key.  Since an already installed OEM license cannot be transfered, what exactly are you trying to do, because something isn't right.

Comment: @Ramhound Isn't right is to speculate and to downvote based on speculations. It was simply a question whether it is possible or not possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find the product key that was used to activate Windows 8?](http://superuser.com/questions/495794/how-can-i-find-the-product-key-that-was-used-to-activate-windows-8) also see [Is there a product key finder for a PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/176306/is-there-a-product-key-finder-for-a-pc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible by design. The key  is stored in an encrypted part of the system registry, and cannot be accessed by a normal user because MS believes it will aid piracy, allowing malware authors the ability to steal the key. you will need some external program (I've had luck with MagicJellyBean on win7) to break in and retrieve it.

Comment: Or Product key finder to the least. Yeah..!

Comment: @Frank-thomas thank you for the info.